# Построить дерево php (массив + объекты)

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, дерево

Пытаюсь бороться с рекурсией, не могу понять как сделать правильный массив.
Есть текущий массив с объектами (id, name, parent):

```
array:5 [▼
  "c3fdb653-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7" => Category {#438 ▼
    +id: "c3fdb653-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Каталог товаров"
    +parent: null
  }
  "c3fdb647-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7" => Category {#444 ▼
    +id: "c3fdb647-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Спецпредложения"
    +parent: "c3fdb653-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
  }
  "c3fdb649-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7" => Category {#443 ▼
    +id: "c3fdb649-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Домашняя медтехника"
    +parent: "c3fdb653-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
  }
```

На выходе хотел получить вот такой массив дерева:

```
array:5 [▼
  "1" => Category {#438 ▼
    +id: "1",
    +external_id: "c3fdb653-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Каталог товаров"
    +parent: null
  }
  "2" => Category {#444 ▼
    +id: "2"
    +external_id: "c3fdb647-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Спецпредложения"
    +parent: "1"
  }
  "3" => Category {#443 ▼
    +id: "3"
    +external_id: "c3fdb649-eba5-11e7-80c4-0cc47ab29cf7"
    +name: "Домашняя медтехника"
    +parent: "1"
  }
```

Comment: Как-то не улавливается зависимость между исходным массивом и конечным деревом

Comment: Да данные те же что и в первом массиве. id это $i++

Comment: Я не вижу в исходном массиве строки `PC Laptops`, а в конечном - `Спецпредложения`

Comment: Извините, поправил пост

Comment: Теперь вообще другой результат, куда делся children и вложенность?

Comment: И опять не понятно. Если `Category` - это класс, то откуда у него возьмется поле `external_id`?

Comment: external_id = id в исходном массиве

Comment: Наверное проще да же так вопрос задать, как мне самый первый массив записать в базу данных, деревом, при том что значение родителей (parent_id) должны быть не строкой как сейчас, а integer id и parent_id

Comment: сделайте `$arr = array_keys($your_array); array_unshft($arr, 1); unset($arr[0]);` - это массив соответствий новых и старых id. дальше обычный цикл. Если с нуля начинать, два последних опрератора выбросьте

Comment: Спасибо попробую.